# Deriving marginal pdf from joint pdf

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, conditional-probability, gamma-distribution

Problem setup: $X \sim \Gamma(\alpha,\beta)$, $f_{Y|X}(y|x)= \tau xy^{\tau-1}e^{-xy^\tau}$ for $y>0$ and $f_{Y|X}(y|x)=0$ for $y\leq0$, where $\tau\geq1$ is a constant.

I am asked to derive the marginal pdf of $y$ and am wondering if there is a more direct method than deriving the joint pdf $f(x,y)$ and then deriving $f_Y(y)$ from the joint pdf. I know I can use $f(x,y) = f_{Y|X}(y|x)f(x)$ to derive the joint pdf, but I'm unsure if there is a simpler way. Thanks

Comment: If this is homework, it needs a `self-study` tag.

Comment: Most people are unaware of all the rules when they start using the site, and you are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the change of variable $u=y^{\tau}$. Then, recall that the Gamma distribution is the conjugate prior of the rate parameter in the Exponential distribution. et voila.